# Flutter background service not working in iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to do something with flutter, I want to count the number of steps and on a duration. The goal is to allow the user to drag the app in the background (not quit) while managing the ongoing processes in the app.

I tried some packages like :

workmanager 0.5.1
flutter_background_service 2.4.5
flutter_foreground_task 3.10.0

I've found that everything works fine on Android, but on iOS all processes are paused after about 20 seconds when the app is sent to background.

Comment: I had the same problem. I did not find a plugin that works for iOS in release mode. I was thinking about using method channels but did not try it so far.